# React Native Expo issue

Tags: react-native

*** getting white screen while ***

1. I install React Native with Expo.
2. When I start the app its work normally.
3. After I play for a while with NativeBase UI, it gave me this white screen. Any help.

```js
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React from "react";
import Index from "./src/Home";
import { NativeBaseProvider, Box } from "native-base";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NativeBaseProvider>
      <Index />
    </NativeBaseProvider>
  );
}
```

[Here is the white screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsTH8.png) 
[here is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXZyO.png)

Comment: What's the code in "Home" file? Does it have any View/Text/ Image etc to render?

Comment: its native base code i take it away and still i get the problem its just style component

Comment: native base is only the provider. Without content in your Index component you will not see anything. If we do not see the source of your Index component how should we possibly guess what is going wrong.